# Parse Promise to update multiple rows

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I want to update multiple rows in a class in Parse. I need to add a new field using "set". I tried `saveAll` and `Promises` in parallel to update, but these both are asynchronous. So they consume lot of resources and bandwidth.

How can I do that in a synchronous way. It would be better for me if you can answer using promises in series

Here is the code I'm using currently.But I need in a series way

```
Parse.Cloud.define("Updating",function(request,response){
    var query = new Parse.Query("FollowUp");
    query.find({
        success: function(results){
            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                results[i].set("testfield","sometext");
            }
            Parse.Object.saveAll(results,{
                success: function(list){
                    response.success("ok");
                },
                error: function(error){
                    response.error("failed");
                }
            });
        },
        error: function(error) {}
    });
});
```

Comment: Could you please explain why did you downvote??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is working fine and it is synchronous.

```
Parse.Cloud.define("Updating",function(request,response){
var query = new Parse.Query("FollowUp");
query.find().then(function(results) {
  var promise = Parse.Promise.as();
  _.each(results, function(result) {
    // For each item, extend the promise with a function to save it.
    result.set("newfield","somevalue");
    promise = promise.then(function() {
      // Return a promise that will be resolved when the save is finished.
      return result.save();
    });
  });

  return promise;

}).then(function() {
    response.success("working!!");
  // Every object is updated.
});

});
```

or you can even use "for" loop instead of _.each

```
Parse.Cloud.define("Updating",function(request,response){
var query = new Parse.Query("FollowUp");
query.find().then(function(results) {
  var promise = Parse.Promise.as();
  for(var i=0;i<results.length;i++){
    results[i].set("newfield","somevalue");
    promise = promise.then(function() {
      // Return a promise that will be resolved when the save is finished.
      return results[i].save();
    });
  });

  return promise;

}).then(function() {
    response.success("working!!");
  // Every object is updated.
});

});
```